# getting error while Converting the Html Contenttpo Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

Hello every one i am using HTml Agility and Openxml to convert my html content to word file content.

```
<div>
<div id="container">
<div>
<div>
<!--content starts here//-->
<form name="questions" method="post">
<img src="../../content/0/Static UPload/Divya_3LevelLeftMenu_Operating System v8.0 English/unit9/lesson27/../../images/less_title_27.jpg" width="750" height="75">
<div id="title">Exercise
<table border="0" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><b> Student's Name:&nbsp;</b><br>
      <input type="text" name="b1" size="45"></td>
    <td><b>Class:</b><br>
      <input type="text" name="b2" size="45"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<td width="176" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <tr><td width="779" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
       <ol>
      <li>Describe the purpose of Windows Update. 
      <p align="left"><textarea name="a1" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="55"></textarea></p>
      </li>
    </ol>

    <ol start="2">
      <li>Explain why using Windows Update is critical to maintaining an operating system.
        <p align="left"><textarea name="a2" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="55"></textarea></p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol start="3">
      <li>Summarize the process used to access and install Windows Updates.  
        <p align="left"><textarea name="a3" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="55"></textarea></p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol start="4">
      <li>Compare and contrast using Windows Update and using a Windows Service Pack. 
        <p align="left"><textarea name="a4" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="55"></textarea></p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <center><p><b>Note: You must print your completed exercise
    to submit to your instructor.</b><br>
    <b class="style1"><u>Do Not</u></b> close this window without printing your exercise or your answers will be lost.<br><br>
            <input onclick="reLoadMe(document.questions) " type="button" value="Print Preview">
      </p>
    </center>
</form>
    <div align="center"><a href="#top"><img src="../../content/0/Static UPload/Divya_3LevelLeftMenu_Operating System v8.0 English/unit9/lesson27/../../images/back_to_top.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="21" border="0"></a>

</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

this is the html content i am using to convert.
But i am getting the following error while parsing it.

```
   at NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml.TableContext.get_CurrentTable()
   at NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml.HtmlConverter.ProcessTableColumn(HtmlEnumerator en)
   at NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml.HtmlConverter.ProcessHtmlChunks(HtmlEnumerator en, String endTag)
   at NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml.HtmlConverter.Parse(String html)
   at WebApplication3.WebForm3.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Piyush_training\WebApplication3\WebForm3.aspx.cs:line 102
```

my code is as follows.

```
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
    using NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml;
    using System.IO;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
    using wp = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using System.Text;
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string filename = "C:/Temp/test.docx";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;
        System.Text.StringBuilder SB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        System.IO.StringWriter SW = new System.IO.StringWriter();
```

string pagecontent=*above html Content*;
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(pagecontent);
                if (doc == null) ;
                doc.OptionCheckSyntax = true;
                doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
                doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                int errorCount = doc.ParseErrors.Count();
                string output = "";

```
            doc.Save(SW);
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(SW);
            strBody = "<html>" + "<body>" + "<div><b>" + htmlTW.InnerWriter.ToString() + "</b></div>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

            string html = strBody; 

           try
            {
                using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                    {
                        MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
                        if (mainPart == null)
                        {
                            mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                            new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                        }

                        HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
                        converter.ExcludeLinkAnchor = true;
                        converter.RefreshStyles();
                        converter.ImageProcessing = ImageProcessing.AutomaticDownload;
                        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
                        converter.ConsiderDivAsParagraph = false;

                        var paragraphs = converter.Parse(html);
                        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
                        {
                            body.Append(paragraphs[i]);
                        }

                        mainPart.Document.Save();
                    }

                    File.WriteAllBytes(filename, generatedDocument.ToArray());
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get content with images working.

To use the AltChunk method you have to use an existent file. Create the file dynamically with any content first, because altChunk doesn't accept a blank file.

1. Create a .docx file with a small content.
2. Append the html content.

---

```
try
{
    var domainNameURL = "yoursite.com/";
    var strBody = "<html>" + "<body>" + "<div> Word File </div>" + "</body>" + "</html>";
    using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
            if (mainPart == null)
            {
                mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
            }

            HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
            converter.ExcludeLinkAnchor = true;
            converter.RefreshStyles();
            converter.ImageProcessing = ImageProcessing.AutomaticDownload;
            converter.BaseImageUrl = new Uri(domainNameURL + "Images/");

            Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
            converter.ConsiderDivAsParagraph = false;

            var paragraphs = converter.Parse(strBody);
                for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
                {
                    body.Append(paragraphs[i]);
                }

            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, generatedDocument.ToArray());
    }

    using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        XNamespace r = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships";
        string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart("application/xhtml+xml", altChunkId);

        using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))
            stringStream.Write(html);
        XElement altChunk = new XElement(w + "altChunk",
        new XAttribute(r + "id", altChunkId)
        );
        XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = GetXDocument(myDoc);
        mainDocumentXDoc.Root
            .Element(w + "body")
            .Elements(w + "p")
            .Last()
            .AddAfterSelf(altChunk);
        SaveXDocument(myDoc, mainDocumentXDoc);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You can find `GetXDocument` and `SaveXDocument` methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7768263/1863970

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a different approach for assembling your word document from HTML. Depending on your requirements you can take one of a couple of approaches:

1. Assemble the document using the OpenXmlSdk as you have done, **or**:
2. Use the **altChunk** method

> altChunk, is a special feature of Open XML word processing
>   markup that enables you to embed an entire Open XML document or an
>   **html page** at a specific location in a document

Eric White has a number of blog posts describing this process, below is an extract from his article highlighting embedding html:

Using V2 of the Open XML SDK:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test1.docx", true))
{
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("TestInsertedContent.docx", FileMode.Open))
        chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
     AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
     altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
     mainPart.Document
         .Body
         .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
     mainPart.Document.Save();
 }
```

The whole article along with sample code (at the bottom): [How to Use altChunk for Document Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx)

Comment: Does it work for the Images also.Please tell me how can i show images while converting from html content to word document.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to convert a huge HTML (with inline images) to Word, after reading previous answers and the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152334/1863970

```
public static byte[] HtmlToWord(string html)
{
    using (var generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
            if (mainPart == null)
            {
                mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
            }

            HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
            Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

            string altChunkId = "myId";

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body>" + html + "</body></html>"));

            // Create alternative format import part.
            var formatImportPart = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, altChunkId);

            // Feed HTML data into format import part (chunk).
            formatImportPart.FeedData(memoryStream);
            var altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

            mainPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }

        return generatedDocument.ToArray();
    }
}
```